# SSRS Report - Creating Calendar Style Report with Multiple Data in a Single Calendar Cell

Tags: reporting-services, calendar, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to achieve calendar style report using this link :

http://msdyn.blogspot.com/2013/07/create-calendar-style-reports-in-sql.html

But this Calendar Style Report is for the Sum of Sales.
[image]

[image]

My desired result of the report is to return a list of employees in a Calendar cell. But it returns redundant day numbers. I am seeking for advise on how to remove the redundancy of the **day numbers** (I want multiple employees in one calendar cell). (Screenshot below). Any suggestions please? Thank you in advance!

[image][image]

Comment: Is Week Number a group?  You'll also need to group on Day Number and place it in a header row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a Sub-report in order to fix the issue.

[image]